# How to obtain the traffic signs belonging to a set of LINK_IDS

Tags: rest, maps, here-api

I am using the REST API of HERE. I am trying to obtain the traffic signs corresponding to a set of LINK_IDS.

I have a list of the links (unique IDs) I am interested in, however I do not know how to obtain the traffic signs which are found in these links. As I understand there should only be 1 traffic sign in each link, at the end of the link.

Can anyone hint what is the way to proceed? I was trying to use Platform Data Extension API to do this, but have not been successful.

The most I have been able to achieve is obtaining all the traffic signs in one tile, by querying the following:

```
http://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/tile.json?region=EU
&release=LATEST
&layer=TRAFFIC_SIGN_FC1
&level=9
&tilex=537&tiley=399
&app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={APP_CODE}
```

However, this is not even working for all locations. I tried in different parts of the city of London and the output I obtain is:

```
{
  "Rows": 
  Array[0][

  ]
}
```

In summary, my goal is to obtain the corresponding traffic sign (s) in a link. That is, for link with ID XXXXXXXXX I would like to see which is the traffic sign present in the location marked by this link.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to obtain the traffic signs corresponding to a set of LINK_IDS

There is no straight solution to this yet. You have to use PDE layer which gets all traffic information for a tile and then extract the link ids of your interest. We have 100% coverage in WEU and NA. For MEA, we have 100% coverage on FC1-FC4 roads and less coverage on FC5 roads(which are destination roads).